# cant get 100,000+ hebrew characters into objective-c string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have 100,000+ characters of text that need to be converted into a string so I can count the characters and display them on a page correctly, but in the text there are tons of quotations ("") and lots of commas, so it doesnt even turn into a string. 
Does anyone know a way that you can ignore quotations and commas inside a NSString without having to do this \"" each time?

Here's some of the text. its english/hebrew

Psalm 30
...
Psalm 100
...

The following Psalm is not to be said on Shabbat, Festivals, the day before Pesach, Chol HaMoed Pesach, and the day of Yom Kippur
...

Comment: What is the source of the characters you are converting? Are the quotes and commas part of the text to be included? Or just formatting of the source data?
What have you tried so far?

Comment: the valid answer would be: yes.

Comment: yes the quotes and commas part of the text to be included

Comment: I'll include some of the text

Comment: Did you look how to escape a quotation sign?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  Do you want to make a copy of the string, omitting the punctuation?  Or do you want to “do some manipulation” on the string (e.g. transliterate each Hebrew character to English), preserving the punctuation?  Be more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: several people pointed out laws in your question. so why are you surprised about down votes?

Comment: @Larme yes but I have not found a good answer

Comment: @NewEngland, why have not you asked your client to present the data in final format for the application? or would it be a kind of dynamic content not a bundle-related?

Comment: @vikingosegundo people are so quick to down vote a question. Instead of just telling me whats wrong, they down vote first and wait for me to ask... I'm a beginner, and its just ridiculous how cold people are when you dont know the slightest thing..

Comment: @holex i'm doing it on my own (no client) and im just pulling it off this [website](http://opensiddur.org/siddurim/nusa%E1%B8%A5-ha-ari-a-new-transcription-by-shmuel-gonzales/) its going to be static content

Comment: maybe you are too quick to ask a question. before hitting save you should make sure the question is complete.

Comment: also your question is answered thousands if times for sure.

Comment: the problem is that I cant even turn the text into a string becuase of the hebrew text, quotations, etc.. I have not seen another question like this. if there is one, please provide a link

Comment: for the NSString it doesn't matter if it is latin, hebrew or hindu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say “I cant even turn the text into a string”.  Since you said (in a comment) you're “just pulling it off this website”, the simplest way to do this is `+[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:]`.  This works for me:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/The-Blessing-Book-Nusa%E1%B8%A5-Ha-Ari-%E1%B8%A4aBaD-3.2.txt"];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:nil error:&error];
    NSLog(@"error=%@ text.length=%lu", error, (unsigned long)text.length);
```

You can look into `NSURLSession` or `NSURLConnection` when you want to do it in a non-blocking fashion.

If you plan to distribute the text in a file (named, let's say, “blessingBook.txt”) in your app bundle, you can get the URL this way:

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"blessingBook" withExtension:@"txt"];
```

If you're loading it directly from your app bundle, you probably don't need to worry about using `NSURLSession` to load it in the background.  You might want to do your “processing” in the background though, if it takes a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the punctuation or commas or what ever you want to @"" (empty string).

```
yourString=[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

yourString=[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];

yourString=[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@""];
```

What ever the text you want to replace. Replace as above.

But it is lengthy process finding un wanted quotations, commas..some characters and replace with empty string..

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: the problem is that I cant even get the text into a string to begin with, so I forsure cant do any nsstring methods on it :(